# CSS Clip - Sprite Image

Tags: css, clip

I have a sprite image which I want to display 128x89px portions across multiple span elements.

In the example I have set the left-clip to 30px to highlight the issue, normally this would be in multiples of 128px. When I set the left clip to 30px, it seems to add 30px left margin. Surely, I don't need to add a negative left margin to correct it?

I am a total newbie to `clip` as I have never really needed to use it, but now there is. My understanding of it is the same as a square cut out of a piece of paper. Adjusting the clip values will move the piece of paper around therefore changing the viewed image.

Please help.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/VgjXr/

**CSS:**

```
a {  
    border: 1px solid #000;  
    height: 89px;  
    width: 128px;  
    display: block;  
}
span.image {  
    background-image: url('http://i1269.photobucket.com/albums/jj591/mark1979smith/splice.jpg');  
    position: absolute;  
    display: block;  
    width: 128px;  
    height: 89px;  
    clip: rect(0px,158px,89px,30px);  
    clear: both;  
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="element" id="cheeseOption7">   
    <div id="optional_46">
        <a href="#">                    
            <span class="image"><!--  --></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best explaination I have found on `clip` is [at this site](http://www.ibloomstudios.com/articles/misunderstood_css_clip/), though I think you do have a generally correct grasp of how it works. What you are not grasping is how that relates to your situation. The `clip` is occuring on the background image of the `span`. Your `30px` is telling the browser to clip off the image 30px from the left (which is exactly what your fiddle example is doing), but *it does not affect the positioning of the background*.

**Using sprites, one does not normally use `clip`, but `background-position`** to switch sprite image position in relation to the element it is displayed in. So for your 128px x 89px sprite images, you would start with `background-position: 0 0` and move to `-189px 0` to shift one image to the right or `0 -89px` to shift one image down.

I assume because `clip` requires `position: absolute` is why you are using the `span`, but in fact, because you really should use `background-position`, it will allow you to eliminate the `span` all together, and just do the positioning on the background of the `a` element directly.

Comment: Fantastic, Thank you! I guess because I had it in my head to use clip (and to finally get around to using it) I stuck with it. Now I know that it's not the correct place to use it, I've reverted back to good old background-position.

Comment: sprites with clip is the norm if you are take into consideration high density pixels, like ipad3

Comment: @albert--I'm curious to understand your comment better. Can you point me to some documentation that shows how and why `clip` is used in such a case as opposed to `background-position`? I'm not sure how high density pixels would matter.